# How do I count the 10 most common words in a multiple lists of tokenized words

Tags: python, count, nlp, cpu-word

I have a data-set with a lot of lists of lists of tokenized words.
for example:

```
['apple','banana','tomato']
['tomato','tree','pikachu']
```

I have around 40k lists like those, and I want to count the 10 most common words from all of the 40k lists together.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could flatten the nested list with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and take the most common words using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its `most_common` method:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

l = ['apple','banana','tomato'],['tomato','tree','pikachu']

Counter(chain(*l)).most_common(10)
# [('tomato', 2), ('apple', 1), ('banana', 1), ('tree', 1), ('pikachu', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution using dictionary

```
arrays = [['apple','banana','tomato'],['tomato','tree','pikachu']]
d = dict()
for array in arrays:
    for item in array:
        if item in d:
            d[item] += 1
        else:
            d[item] = 1
print(sorted( ((v,k) for k,v in d.items()), reverse=True)[:10])
```

Output

```
[('tomato', 2), ('apple', 1), ('banana', 1), ('tree', 1), ('pikachu', 1)]
```

Comment: using a [defaultdict(int)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could make this a slight bit easier as well (see 3rd example)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to merge your lists to a one list e.g.

```
list_of_lists = [['apple','banana','tomato'],['tomato','tree','pikachu']]

import itertools
flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*list_of_lists))
```

Then use Counter to calculate your tokens and pick just the top 10

```
from collections import Counter
counter_of_flat_list = Counter(flat_list)

print(counter_of_flat_list.most_common(10)) # print top 10
```

[('tomato', 2), ('apple', 1), ('banana', 1), ('tree', 1), ('pikachu', 1)]